# Sorting a list of ordered dictionaries in Pandas for csv output

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have added a dbf file into a Pandas series dataframe. The original data is in a listed dictionary like so.

```
0       {'a': 'av1','b': 'bv1', 'c' : 'cv1',...
1       {'a': 'av2', b': 'bv2', 'c' : 'cv2',...
2       {'a': 'av3', b': 'bv3', 'c' : 'cv3',...
3       {'a': 'av4', b': 'bv4', 'c' : 'cv4',...
4       {'a': 'av5', b': 'bv5', 'c' : 'cv5',...
```

What's the best way with or without pandas to get it output into a dataframe/csv (pivoting the keys into columns)

Desired output:

```
    a     b      c  ...
0  av1   bv1    cv1 ...
1  av2   bv2    cv2 ...
2  av3   bv3    cv3 ...
3  av4   bv4    cv4 ...
4  av5   bv5    cv5 ...
...
```

Comment: you mean `pd.DataFrame(df['col_name'].tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0):

We need to do `ast` then pass to `DataFrame`

```
import ast
yourdf = pd.DataFrame(df['col_name'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())
Out[191]: 
     a    b    c
0  av1  bv1  cv1
1  av1  bv1  cv1
```